# How many gateways need to be configured for a 2 IP on 1 NIC setup?

Tags: networking, systemd

Is this better? (currently used and working good)

```
[ipv4]
address1=10.0.0.13/32
address2=10.0.0.42/32
gateway1=10.0.0.1
gateway2=10.0.0.1
dns=10.0.0.1;
dns-search=
method=manual
```

or should I only define one gateway? (nmtui suggests this way)

```
[ipv4]
address1=10.0.0.13/32,10.0.0.1
address2=10.0.0.42/32
dns=10.0.0.1;
dns-search=
method=manual
```

- gateway after the client IP?
- gateway as separate lines?
- is defining multiple gateways harmful when the same?
- how do I know which connection will be preferred?

You can see, I have put some thought into this. What I have is working fine, but is it the correct way to do it? The complete networking model before systemd.networking had way better documentation.

Comment: You only need one gateway

Comment: I do not think the order matters

Comment: And the usual warning: Multiple IPv4 addresses on a single interface may cause headaches. Make sure all applications you use can bind to a particular address, or you may have fun debugging network issues. Or use some other solution, like network namespaces.

Comment: always only one default gateway, as many routes as needed to other networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gavery@debianbox:~ $ cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/

gavery@debianbox:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections $ sudo cat raspberry_wired

```
[connection]
id=raspberry_wired
uuid=717d0eb0-7dad-36c4-8552-3da0fc93b912
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-999
permissions=
timestamp=1540761774

[ethernet]
mac-address=B8:27:EB:AF:F3:F4
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
address1=10.0.0.17/32,10.0.0.1
dns=10.0.0.1;
dns-search=
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

gavery@debianbox:/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections $ sudo cat raspberry_slave

```
[connection]
id=raspberry_slave
uuid=a5cb2a46-06c2-42bc-b40d-0895a434f031
type=ethernet
permissions=
timestamp=1540761125

[ethernet]
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
address1=10.0.0.39/32
dns=10.0.0.1;
dns-search=
method=manual
never-default=true

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Do note the important setting on the slave connection:

```
never-default=true
```

This will (hopefully) prevent software on your server from using the slave connection, unless particularly forced.
I use this to run two DNS servers facing LAN on the same box under 2 different client IPs, using the same port:

```
10.0.0.17:53
10.0.0.39:53
```